# Flutter @Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am building a Flutter application, the app ran upto mark while i was building for Android but as i started building the app for iOS i started facing error of "Null Safety features are disabled for this library"

**The Error is as follows :**

```
Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:100:4: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
Uri? _currentUriBase;
   ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:106:7: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
String? _current;
      ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:120:16: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        [String? part2,
               ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:121:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part3,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:122:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part4,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:123:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part5,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:124:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part6,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:125:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part7]) =>
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:258:16: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        [String? part2,
               ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:259:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part3,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:260:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part4,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:261:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part5,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:262:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part6,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:263:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part7,
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:264:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
        String? part8]) =>
              ^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.8.0-nullsafety/lib/path.dart:358:37: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
String relative(String path, {String? from}) =>
                                    ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:126:9: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  Object? invoke(covariant T intent);
        ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:235:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:330:50: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  Object invoke(covariant T intent, [BuildContext? context]);
                                                 ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:334:52: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
typedef OnInvokeCallback<T extends Intent> = Object? Function(T intent);
                                                   ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:361:9: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  Object? invoke(covariant T intent) => onInvoke(intent);
        ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:386:9: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  Object? invokeAction(covariant Action<Intent> action, covariant Intent intent, [BuildContext? context]) {
        ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:386:95: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  Object? invokeAction(covariant Action<Intent> action, covariant Intent intent, [BuildContext? context]) {
                                                                                              ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:420:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:436:25: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final ActionDispatcher? dispatcher;
                        ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:495:22: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  static VoidCallback? handler<T extends Intent>(BuildContext context, T intent, {bool nullOk = false}) {
                     ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:510:19: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  static Action<T>? find<T extends Intent>(BuildContext context, {bool nullOk = false}) {
                  ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:595:16: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  static Object? invoke<T extends Intent>(
               ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:653:22: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  Set<Action<Intent>>? listenedActions = <Action<Intent>>{};
                     ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:718:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:719:21: Error: Expected '}' before this.
    required Widget child,
                    ^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:724:25: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final ActionDispatcher? dispatcher;
                        ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:887:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:914:18: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
                 ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:920:34: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final Map<Type, Action<Intent>>? actions;
                                 ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:923:35: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final Map<LogicalKeySet, Intent>? shortcuts;
                                  ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:929:27: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final ValueChanged<bool>? onShowFocusHighlight;
                          ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:934:27: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final ValueChanged<bool>? onShowHoverHighlight;
                          ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:939:27: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final ValueChanged<bool>? onFocusChange;
                          ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:1031:41: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  void _mayTriggerCallback({VoidCallback? task, FocusableActionDetector? oldWidget}) {
                                        ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:1031:72: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  void _mayTriggerCallback({VoidCallback? task, FocusableActionDetector? oldWidget}) {
                                                                       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:121:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:164:17: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final Duration? reverseDuration;
                ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:250:22: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  AnimationController? _controller;
                     ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:251:8: Error: A method declaration needs an explicit list of parameters.
Try adding a parameter list to the method declaration.
  late Animation<double> _firstAnimation;
       ^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:251:26: Error: Expected '{' before this.
  late Animation<double> _firstAnimation;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:251:26: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
  late Animation<double> _firstAnimation;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:252:8: Error: A method declaration needs an explicit list of parameters.
Try adding a parameter list to the method declaration.
  late Animation<double> _secondAnimation;
       ^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:252:26: Error: Expected '{' before this.
  late Animation<double> _secondAnimation;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:252:8: Error: 'Animation' is already declared in this scope.
  late Animation<double> _secondAnimation;
       ^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:251:8: Context: Previous declaration of 'Animation'.
  late Animation<double> _firstAnimation;
       ^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:252:26: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
  late Animation<double> _secondAnimation;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:274:3: Error: 'Animation' isn't a type.
  Animation<double> _initAnimation(Curve curve, bool inverted) {
  ^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_cross_fade.dart:274:3: Context: This isn't a type.
  Animation<double> _initAnimation(Curve curve, bool inverted) {
  ^^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:33:28: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final AnimationController? controller;
                           ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:34:39: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder? removedItemBuilder;
                                      ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:272:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:340:25: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final ScrollController? controller;
                        ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:350:13: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final bool? primary;
            ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:358:22: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final ScrollPhysics? physics;
                     ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:377:27: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? padding;
                          ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:388:27: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  static AnimatedListState? of(BuildContext context, { bool nullOk = false }) {
                          ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:737:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:774:33: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  static SliverAnimatedListState? of(BuildContext context, {bool nullOk = false}) {
                                ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:837:14: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  _ActiveItem? _removeActiveItemAt(List<_ActiveItem> items, int itemIndex) {
             ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:842:14: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  _ActiveItem? _activeItemAt(List<_ActiveItem> items, int itemIndex) {
             ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_size.dart:57:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_size.dart:58:11: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Widget? child,
          ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_size.dart:101:17: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final Duration? reverseDuration;
                ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_switcher.dart:64:63: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
typedef AnimatedSwitcherLayoutBuilder = Widget Function(Widget? currentChild, List<Widget> previousChildren);
                                                              ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_switcher.dart:149:8: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
    Key? key,
       ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_switcher.dart:175:15: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
  final Widget? child;
              ^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_switcher.dart:192:17: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.10 or higher.
```

**The error also shows that required isn't a type**

```
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:400:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.filter,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:820:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required ShapeBorder shape,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:907:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.color,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:999:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.clipper,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1002:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.color,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1114:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.transform,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1151:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required double angle,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1180:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required Offset offset,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1219:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required double scale,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1301:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.link,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1361:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.link,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1507:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.translation,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1569:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.quarterTurns,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1644:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.padding,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1921:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.delegate,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1951:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required this.id,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1952:5: Error: 'required' isn't a type.
    required Widget child,
    ^^^^^^^^
/Users/himanshu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0-nullsafety.2/lib/meta.dart:224:16: Context: This isn't a type.
const Required required = Required();
               ^^^^^^^^
```

**The flutter doctor -v goes as follows :**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 216dee60c0 (3 weeks ago), 2020-09-01 12:24:47 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ashu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 30.0.0-rc2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)   
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.49.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Ashu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Thank you.

Comment: change in your pubspec.yaml the enviroment -sdk verrsion to >= 2.10.0 and run pub get or upgrade

Answer (score 27):

I solved it by doing the following (for Visual Code on Windows 10):

in Command prompt (or whichever terminal you use with flutter in PATH):

`flutter upgrade`

And made sure that the version is at least 2.12 (which is the minimum required version for enabling null safety without using it as an experimental feature (I believe ))

```
PS C:\> flutter upgrade
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.0.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git 
Framework • revision 8962f6dc68 (2 days ago) • 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
Engine • revision 5d8bf811b3
Tools • Dart 2.12.1
```

When that was confirmed, then I checked what my current sdk-version in the project was (in my case it was the following: `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`)

So I updated it to be the following instead: `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`.

So the environment in pubspec.yaml should look as following:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: should mention update sdk version in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 4):

switch to dev/master channel

try to add sdk (that supports null safety) in `pubspec.yaml` file.
In my case

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-27.0.dev <2.12.0"
```

create `analysis_options.yaml` & add

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

[optional]

if u r using vs code try to add

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "name",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "vmAdditionalArgs": [
            "--enable-experiment=non-nullable",
        ],
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the My solution in Android studio

1. Add below line to your pubspec.yaml

> ```
> analyzer:
>   enable-experiment:
>   - non-nullable
> ```

2. Upgrade your **SDK** in pubspec.yaml

> ```
> environment:
>   sdk: ">=2.13.0-68.0.dev <3.0.0"
> ```

This works for me...!!!!

Example

```
>     analyzer:
>       enable-experiment:
>       - non-nullable
>     
>     environment:   
>       sdk: ">=2.13.0-68.0.dev <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

[[image: Like here]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s96v.png)Here is my solution (on android studio )
It's working fine for me----------->

```
version: 1.0.0+1

analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0-213.1.beta <3.0.0"
```

Comment: can i add analyzer without changing sdk version?
cuz if i chnage my sdk version my application will show a lot of errors at this point, how i can i remove this nullable error without upgrading sdk?

Comment: Yes you can, for this you have to use older version. But I'm always support to use update version. But for conflict of package version you can create a question and give me the link I can explain or I can give you the solution or if you know how to use "dependency_overrides:"

Comment: Sure I'll post the question and will provide you with the link. and I don't know dependency overrides as i am new to Flutter and i am still learning it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448617/error-null-safety-features-are-disabled-for-this-library-in-flutter

Here's the link to my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67454439/7760245  here you will find the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

//This worked for me on Android Studio 2020.3.1; flutter ver 2.5.3 stable

environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

//I changed it to 2.12.0 it it worked. John 3:16 for eternal life